Laravel 10 redirect to specific route gives error
Working with Laravel 10, Windows 10, Wamp.
I am trying to redirect users that have a specific permission to a different page than the home page.
Or, if they tried to login from the shop page, then redirect them back to the shop's page.
Trying to login, I get this error:

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1
($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
given, called in
C:\wamp64\www\highland10.local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php
on line 72

I change the code in the LoginController to something else, I commit, it works fine, then the day after, or moving to a different computer, I get the error.
I change the code again, works fine, the day after or a different computer, the same error.
In my routes file I have this:
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'can:admin dashboard'], function () {
    Route::get('/bean', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');
});

The codes I tried, in LoginController:
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{        
    $previousUrl = Session::get('previousUrl', '/');
    
    $url = session()->get('url.intended');
    
    if($previousUrl != '/') {
        Session::forget('previousUrl');            
        return redirect($previousUrl);
    } else { 
        if (auth()->user()->can('admin dashboard'))
            return redirect('/bean'); // the problematic code
    }
    
    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}

Worked fine, then the day after, got the error.
Changed the code, instead of:
return redirect('/bean');

Changed to:
return to_route('admin');    

Worked fine until the day after. Sometimes it works fine for days, and then out of the blue, gives the error.
Can anyone please help?

Try redirecting to a named route and using named routes instead of urls in Session:
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{        
    $previousRoute = Session::get('previousRoute'); //store your route names instead of urls
    
    //$url = session()->get('url.intended'); // this line is redundant
    
    if($previousRoute != 'home') { //change 'home' to match your name for the '/' route
        Session::forget('previousRoute');            
        return redirect()->route($previousRoute);
    } else { 
        if (auth()->user()->can('admin dashboard')) {
            return redirect()->route('admin'); //using 'admin' route as per your example
        }
    }
    
    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}


Thank you, I tried that as well, same issue.

An update, today on the laptop, I got the error. I logged out, logged in again, went fine. What is going on?

Shows your session is getting corrupt somewhere

you should dd/print_r your session variables

Thank you but where should I dd and what? dd(session())?
I tried it in the LoginController and got a session manager output. Not sure what should I look for there?

dd(Session::all());

Thank you again, and where should I put it? in the LoginController?

all the way up and down your stack until it has something that's wrong

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927561/how-to-debug-laravel-framework

Thank you very much @Ballard I will check your link
